# Проверка пустых полей

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть форма:

```
<form class="rf" method="post" action="">
            <input type="text" id="login" placeholder="введите логин" />
            <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="введите пароль" />
            <input type="button"  value="Войти" id="button_enter">
</form>
```

Как с помощью jquery при нажатии на кнопку «Войти» проверить заполняемость текстовых инпутов и если значение какого-либо инпута пустое – данному инпуту присвоить класс `error`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.rf').on('click', '#button_enter', function(){
    $('.rf input:not([type=button])').removeClass('error'); 
    let hasErrors = false;

    $('.rf input:not([type=button])').each(function(){
        if ($(this).val().trim() == '') {
          hasErrors = true;
          $(this).addClass('error');    
        }
    });  
    
    return hasErrors ? false : true; // тут отправка формы либо вернуть false
});
```

```css
.error {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="rf" method="post" action="">
  <input type="text" id="login" placeholder="введите логин" />
  <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="введите пароль" />
  <input type="button" value="Войти" id="button_enter">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const form = document.querySelector('.rf');
const el = [].slice.call(form.elements);

document.getElementById('button_enter').addEventListener('click', () => {
  el.forEach(item => {
    if (!item.value) {
      item.classList.add('error')
    }
  });
})
```

```css
.error {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<form class="rf" method="post" action="">
  <input type="text" id="login" mplaceholder="введите логин" />
  <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="введите пароль" />
  <input type="button" value="Войти" id="button_enter">
</form>
```