# Проверка пустого поля input

Tags: javascript, jquery

```html
<div class="field__input-wrapper"><label class="field__label field__label--visible" for="checkout_shipping_address_first_name">Ф.И.О</label>
  <input name="order_fio" placeholder="Ф.И.О" autocomplete="shipping given-name" data-backup="first_name" class="field__input" size="30" type="text" name="order_fio" " id="order_fio ">
  </div>

<button style="margin-top:15px; " type="submit " name="submitdata " id="confirm-button-next "  name="button " type="submit " class="step__footer__continue-btn btn ">
  <span class="btn__content ">Оформить заказ</span>
  <i class="btn__spinner icon icon--button-spinner "></i>
</button>
```

Как сделать, чтобы по нажатию на кнопку, в случае пустого поля, отображалось, например, "Заполните поле Ф.И.О!"?

Comment: покажите код, как Вы пытались самостоятельно решить задачу

Comment: @Alex оу, опять Вы, добрый человек :) я пытался сделать просто через  required но меня этот вариант не устроил так как нельзя изменить текст ошибки и сам стиль

Comment: а как Вы пытались сделать через js ?

Comment: @Alex никак....

Comment: а как же гугл ? или совсем не хочется попробовать разобраться самостоятельно?

Comment: @Alex да, пробовал по данному видео-уроку https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AyLGhth_hS0 но ничего не получилось

Comment: вам нужен чистый js или jquery?  и где должно быть написано "*Заполните поле Ф.И.О!*" ?

Comment: @Alex мне честно говоря без разницы, главное чтобы работало и на основании я мог делать ещё такие проверки на остальные поля. А писало чтобы под самим полем.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Проверка пустых полей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/747836/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b9)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$("#confirm-button-next").on("click", function() {
  $("div.error").remove();
  if ($("#order_fio").val().length < 1) {
    $("#order_fio").after('<div class="error">Заполните поле Ф.И.О!</div>');
    setTimeout(function(){$("div.error").remove();}, 5000);
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field__input-wrapper"><label class="field__label field__label--visible" for="checkout_shipping_address_first_name">Ф.И.О</label>
  <input name="order_fio" placeholder="Ф.И.О" autocomplete="shipping given-name" data-backup="first_name" class="field__input" size="30" type="text" id="order_fio">
</div>

<button style="margin-top:15px;" type="submit" name="submitdata" id="confirm-button-next" name="button" type="submit" class="step__footer__continue-btn btn">
  <span class="btn__content">Оформить заказ</span>
  <i class="btn__spinner icon icon--button-spinner"></i>
</button>
```

---

*разберитесь с кодом, у Вас по несколько `name` для одного элемента, пробелы в скобках, лишние кавычки и т.п.*

Comment: не работает.....

Comment: код работает. для проверки нажмите на кнопку "выполнить код" , потом на кнопку "оформить заказ". Возможно Вам нужно добавить jquery на страницу: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @ВасилийПупкин совет: научитесь пользоваться инструментами разработчика в вашем браузере. Код работает в примере. Возможно у вас он на что-то ругается. Всегда прикладывайте ошибку или факт её отсутствия к посту.

Comment: @GONG спасибо за совет!

Comment: @Alex да, теперь работает, но после нажатия на "Оформить заказ" страница перезагружается и данные летят всё равно в бд с пустыми ячейками

Comment: @ВасилийПупкин это уже относится к вашей серверной части. Чтобы страница не перезагружалась вам стоит изучить ajax запросы.

P.s. уроки с ютуба, которые вы кидали - ужасны, там даже в комментах народ жалуется что код не рабочий.

Comment: @ВасилийПупкин обновили код. обращаем Ваше внимание, что ответ дается только на опубликованный вопрос (и код в нем), поэтому обо всех подробностях стоит писать сразу.

Comment: @Alex работает, добрый человек :) для остальных полей делать по этому же примеру? и ещё, пожалуйста, могли бы ещё добавить пример с таймером то есть чтобы через заданное время уведомление "Заполните поле" пропадало, к примеру через 5 секунд

Comment: @ВасилийПупкин добавили. *для остальных полей делать по этому же примеру?* - да.

Comment: @Alex круто! скажите, я не правильно что-то сделал? хотел добавить ещё одну проверку http://prntscr.com/hfn6d3

Comment: @ВасилийПупкин поместите код в `$(function(){ ... });`

Comment: @Alex да, заработало, спасибо Вам! И последняя просьба, если не трудно, могли бы сделать 1 пример куда можно вводить только буквы а 2 пример куда можно вводить только цифры? И подскажите, пожалуйста, как менять расположение вывода ошибок? К примеру я хочу чтобы постоянно вверху всех полей писало а не под каждым полем :)

Comment: @ВасилийПупкин Не трудно. Создайте новый вопрос или воспользуйтесь поиском по сайту, такой вопрос скорее всего уже был. Одно из главный правил stackoverflow "Вопрос — ответ. Ничего лишнего." Комментарии предназначены для уточнения решения на вопрос, а не для новых вопросов.