# ajax beforeSend, удаление пробелов

Tags: ajax, валидация

Есть код рабочий с аяс. Отправляет данные с формы. В форме тегу  присвоен атрибут required. Проблема: атрибут required пропускает пробелы. Т.е. оставил поле пустым нажал на пробел, для него это норм. Помогите, как сделать, чтобы и при пробелах выскакивало "заполните это поле"?

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#form1").submit(function() { //устанавливаем событие отправки для формы с id=form
            var form_data = $(this).serialize(); //собераем все данные из формы
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST", //Метод отправки
                url: "phpmailer/index.php", //путь до php фаила отправителя
                data: form_data,

                success: function() {       //код в этом блоке выполняется при успешной отправке сообщения

                    $('#form1').find('input,textarea').val('');
                    alert("Ваше сообщение отправлено!");
                }

            });

            return false;
        });
    });
```

```html
<div id="result"><h3>Введите ваше сообщение и наш консультант свяжется с вами!</h3><br></div>
                <form name="form1" id="form1" action="index.php" method="post">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" required placeholder="Имя" />
                    <br />
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" required placeholder="Телефон" />
                    <br />
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" required placeholder="Почта" />
                    <br />
                    <textarea rows="4" class="form-control" cols="20" name="mail" required placeholder="Сообщение" ></textarea>
                    <br />
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" name="button" id="btn" value="" />
                        Отправить
                    </button>
                </form>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Проверка пустых полей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/747836/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b9)

Comment: Обрабатывайте данные на этапе ввода. Событие `input` для элементов `required` и тримим -  `$(this).val( $.trim($(this).val()) );`

Comment: @Deonis можно поподробней код привести, а то я новичек (т.е тупой) в коде. спасибо

Comment: `$(':required').on('input', function(){
 $(this).val($.trim($(this).val()));
});`

Answer (score 0):

нашел один вариант_:

```js
function check(){
        if(document.getElementById("name").value==" ")
            document.getElementById("name").value="";
    }
```

```html
 <form name="form1" id="form1" action="index.php" method="post">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" required placeholder="Имя" onkeyup="check()" id="name"/>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" name="button" id="btn" value="" />
                        Отправить
                    </button>
</form>
```